# Threading in Pygame causing Memory leak

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-leaks, pygame, python-multithreading

I am creating an Asteroids Game. the game is intended for use over long periods of time.

on startup (using pycharms debugg tool) i am using roughly 30.1 MB of system memory. however i have noticed that while running, it increases by roughly 0.1 MB every second (with a fixed fps of 60). while testing and setting fps to unlimited, i have noticed that memory usage increases respectively to fps increase.

```
import pygame
import math
import random
import threading

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = None
        self.Dimensions = 1000
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((self.Dimensions, self.Dimensions))
        self.fps = 60
        self.MainPage = True
        self.Game = False
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        pygame.init()
    def start(self):
        self.running = True
        self.character = Player()
        self.handler = EventHandler()
        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode((self.Dimensions, self.Dimensions))
        while self.running:
            self.event_list = pygame.event.get()
            for self.event in self.event_list:
                if self.event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False
                    pygame.display.quit()
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
            white = [255, 255, 255]
            self.display.fill(white)
            self.Dimensions = 1000
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)
            self.handler.spawn()
            self.handler.update()
            pygame.display.flip()
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Dimensions = Game.Dimensions
        self.x = self.Dimensions / 2
        self.y = self.Dimensions / 2
        self.looking_directions = 0
        self.velocity = 0
        self.image = "Pictures/Player.png"

class Asteroids():
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 100
        self.x = random.choice(list(set([x for x in range(0, 9)]) - set(range(int(Game.Dimensions/5), int(Game.Dimensions*(4/5))))))
        self.y = random.choice(list(set([x for x in range(0, 9)]) - set(range(int(Game.Dimensions/5), int(Game.Dimensions*(4/5))))))
        self.velocity = random.uniform(1, 2)
        self.looking_direction = random.randrange(0, 360)
        self.picture = "Pictures/Asteroids.png"
        size = 75
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.picture)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (size, size))
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.looking_direction)
    def Update(self):
        
        Game.display.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

class EventHandler():
    def __init__(self):
        self.asteroid_list = []
        self.tick = 0
        self.asteroid_cap = 15
    def spawn(self):
        self.tick += 1
        if len(self.asteroid_list) >= self.asteroid_cap:
            pass
        elif self.tick >= 60:
            temp_asteroid = Asteroids()
            self.asteroid_list.append(temp_asteroid)
            print("Asteroid created: " + str(len(self.asteroid_list)) + " currently alive")
            self.tick = 0
    def update(self):
        for current in self.asteroid_list:

            x = threading.Thread(target=current.Update)
            x.start()
        try:
            x.join()
        except:
            pass
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Game = Main()
    Game.start()
```

EDIT: the memory increase is coming from this function. However now i want to know how to change this change this function so i can keep the threads without the memory increase

```
    def update(self):
        for current in self.asteroid_list:
            x = threading.Thread(target=current.Update)
            y = threading.Thread(target=current.Drift)
            x.start()
            y.start()

        try:
            
            x.join()
            y.join()
        except:
            pass
```

I want to keep the threading (or something as efficient) since from my experience pygame is a bit slow in blitting multiple images at once, so using the loop, i can start the process of blitting them asap and then once they have all started, i call x.join() so no matter what, the threads do not fall behind a frame causing visual bugs or the like.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to create a [mre]. If the minimal example doesn't have the memory leak, congratulations! You can solve your own problem by gradually adding code and fixing the leaky bit. If not, the community may be able to help you.

Comment: @importrandom thank you for this suggestion. i did not understand why i was getting downvotes. I have now uploaded the code that includes the memory leak. I was told a while back to never include my whole code since it clogs up the post and people dont want to go through the whole code for a small memory leak

Comment: Your event handler is creating a thread for each asteroid every game loop iteration, this is probably the cause of your increasing memory usage. I doubt it is necessary. You're also loading and transforming images every loop, which is suboptimal. You should load images once when you create your object. Please look at [pygame sprites](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) and [groups](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) they make doing what you want much easier.

Comment: BTW: Every `update()` of every `Asteroid` is re-loading, re-scaling and re-rotating the bitmap.  This is wasting a *huge* amount of CPU.  Load the bitmap once, pre-scale it.  Then make list containing /N/ rotations of the bitmap, even 360 if you need degree-accuracy.  Then `Asteroid` objects only need to paint the appropriate bitmap out of the list.  The update would become just:  `window.blit( asteroid_images[ int( self.angle) ], ( self.x, self.y ) )`

Comment: can you please explain the list section of you suggestion. i have moved the bitmap loading to Asteroids.__init__() so it only loads once. I dont understand what you mean `by /N/ rotations of the bitmap`

Comment: @importrandom so removing the threading and just calling `current.Update()` etc works fine, however I wanted to practice threading to help just speeding things up in general. I'm not sure why the threading causes this memory increase and how I can keep the threads without the continuous increase in memory usage

also please can you post an answer to this question just so that i can mark it as answered later

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was solved by removing threading completely and replacing the image loading for each object instance with one-time initial image loading.